# Error in fitcecoc, svm training

Tags: svm

```
 trainingSet =  imageSet(imgFolder1, 'recursive');

  % Using HOG Features

 cellSize = [4 4];
 hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);

   %% Train a Digit Classifier

 trainingFeatures = [];
 trainingLabels   = [];

 for digit = 1:numel(trainingSet)

 numImages = trainingSet(digit).Count;           
features  = zeros(numImages, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

for i = 1:numImages

    img = read(trainingSet(digit), i);

    % Apply pre-processing steps
    lvl = graythresh(img);
    img = im2bw(img, lvl);        

    features{i}= extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);
end
 labels= repmat(trainingSet(digit).Description, numImages, 1);

   trainingFeatures=[training features; features];
 trainingLabels=[trainingLabels; labels];

 end

 Classifier=fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, training labels);
```

I am trying to train an svm classifier with this code above.

I get error at the classifier line, saying

Error in fitcecoc: obj=fit(temp, X, Y);

...X must be a numeric matrix

I don't know what to do. Pls help

Comment: By looking at your profile I could tell that you don't seem to reward anyone's efforts to help (by choosing corect answers, replying to comments with feedback on positive results etc.) Why would anyone help you? :-)

Comment: I voted your answer UP CST-Link. I did, or maybe I didn't do it well. Pls am sorry about that.